# Create a directory in Perl for a logfile if it does not exist

Tags: perl, directory, mkdir

I have a Perl script which takes a few arguments. It is executed like this:

```
exec myscript.pl --file=/path/to/input/file --logfile=/path/to/logfile/logfile.log
```

I have the following line in the script:

```
open LOGFILE, ">>$logFilePath" or die "Can't open '$logFilePath': $!\n";
```

Where `$logfilePath` is taken from the command line.
If there is a path, /path/to/logfile/, but no logfile.log, it just creates it (which is the desired action). However, it fails to start if there is no such path. How can I make the script create the path for the logfile, if it does not exist prior to running the script?

Comment: A simple `mkdir -p` will auto-create all necessary parents.

Comment: The problem is that I inherited the file from someone else. I have absolutely no experience with perl whatsoever. I would highly appreciate the full code for that.

Comment: user: calling a unix command in Perl is done with the [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command. Combine that with the mkdir I gave you above.

Comment: Why call a unix command when Perl has its own mkdir function that does exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose you have the path to the logfile (which may or may not include the filename: `logfile.log`) in the variable `$full_path`. Then, you can create the respective directory tree if needed:

```
use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
use File::Path qw( make_path );
use File::Spec;

my ( $logfile, $directories ) = fileparse $full_path;
if ( !$logfile ) {
    $logfile = 'logfile.log';
    $full_path = File::Spec->catfile( $full_path, $logfile );
}

if ( !-d $directories ) {
    make_path $directories or die "Failed to create path: $directories";
}
```

Now, `$full_path` will contain the full path to the `logfile.log` file. The directory tree in the path will have also been created.

Answer (score 7):

Update: as Dave Cross pointed out, `mkdir` only creates a single directory.  So, this won't work if you want to create multiple levels at once.

Use Perl's [`mkdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir.html) command. Example:

```
#Get the path portion only, without the filename.
if ($logFilePath =~ /^(.*)\/[^\/]+\.log$/)
{
    mkdir $1 or die "Error creating directory: $1";
}
else
{
    die "Invalid path name: $logFilePath";
}
```

Using perl's own function is preferable to running a unix command.

Edit: of course, you should also check if the directory exists first.  Use `-e` to check if something exists.  Adding this to the above code:

```
#Get the path portion only, without the filename.
if ($logFilePath =~ /^(.*)\/[^\/]+\.log$/)
{
    if (-e $1) 
    {
        print "Directory exists.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        mkdir $1 or die "Error creating directory: $1";
    }
}
else
{
    die "Invalid path name: $logFilePath";
}
```

Comment: The problem with `mkdir()` is that is can only create one level of directory at a time. If it's possible that you'll be creating multiple levels (and it usually is) then File::Path's `make_path()` is a better suggestion.

Comment: @Dave, thanks for this clarification.  I thought I had tested it with multiple levels, but looking back at what I did, my test was faulty.

Comment: @dan1111 why check if the directory exists first? Wouldn't mkdir() will just fail silently if it doesn't?

Comment: The selector "-e" will return "true" also for file - if we want recursively check if directory exists I suggest to use "-d" instead.